# Generation-based fuzzer

Tags: fuzzing

In general, fuzzers can be categorized into mutation-based and generation-based. Mutation-based fuzzers generate inputs by mutating valid input, whereas generation-based fuzzers generate inputs from scratch and it requires knowledge about the software under test.

But I don't understand how a generation-based fuzzers work? For example, I want to test SQL injection. Can you give me an example what is the information needed to perform generation-based fuzzing and how the process of generating inputs?

Are fuzzers like JBroFuzz and BurpIntruder mutation or generation-based?

Answer (score 0):

If want to write a generation based fuzzer, you will need to write a program that outputs several different "messages." So if you fuzz SQL, your program must output a lot of SQL statements (many of them invalid, presumably). How you go about writing this program is a software engineering (programming) task.

There are several frameworks designed to help you write such programs, but they still require some work.

Answer (score 0):

BurpIntruder can be used to perform both types of fuzzing